# Connecting to a PostGreSQL 7.3 Database in Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I need to connect to an old PostGreSQL database (version 7.3), and I am using Python 3.2 on an XP machine.  The py-postgresql package seemed appropriate, but it seems that it only uses the 3.0 protocol, which was implemented in version 7.4.  I'd like to connect to this database using Python, but when I've tried I have received an unexpected EOF error, which I believe is the result of the package using the newer protocol.

I can use the pgAdminIII program to connect to the database just fine.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, both py-postgresql and psycopg2 only support the v3 protocol.

I think your only option is to use the Postgres ODBC driver, and connect to it using [pyODBC](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) or [mxODBC](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ODBC).  There is a Python 3.x port of pyodbc linked from their main project page.

Comment: I ended up using odbc from pywin32.  It seems to crash python regularly, but I'll figure that one out later.

Answer (score 3):

Try with [PyGreSQL](http://www.pygresql.org/):

> PyGreSQL is a Python module that
>   interfaces to a PostgreSQL database.
>   It embeds the PostgreSQL query library
>   to allow easy use of the powerful
>   PostgreSQL features from a Python
>   script.
>
> The current version PyGreSQL 4.0 needs
>   PostgreSQL 7.2 and Python 2.3 or
>   above.

**EDIT:**

I made some testing against PostgreSQL 7.3 (compiled from [source](ftp://ftp-archives.postgresql.org/pub/source/v7.3.21/) on Debian Squeeze) and I see it works well. I only changed one property in postgresql.conf to make local connections work well under Python:

```
unix_socket_directory = '/var/run/postgresql'
```

After that using [python-pygresql](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/python-pygresql) package (version 4.0.2):

```
import pg
con1 = pg.connect('postgres', None, 5440, None, None, 'postgres', None)
con1.query('SELECT version()')
version
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PostgreSQL 7.3.21 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4
(1 row)
con1.query('SELECT width, height FROM box')
width|height
-----+------
10   |15    
18   |25    
(2 rows)
```